# What are the faulty works by admin will crash the entire system?

Tags: admin

I'm going to give admin access to my client with the following functions disabled

1. magento connect disabled
2. Can't change theme or remove plugin

what else do I need to disable/enable, so that any actions done by admin will not crash the entire system and won't say "can't process your request".

Comment: For my knowledge client requires only `orders` section & if required `Manage Products` section to update the inventory & other information....

Comment: if the above comment worked for you, may i post this as answer ? so that question will not remain as unanswered....

Comment: can you help onething? i have a maegnto site with 12 third party extesions, it was working fine for last 45 days. today suddenly it says  "There has been an error processing your request". what may be the reason? we haven't change anything in admin and magento sysem for last 45 days

Comment: if you have exact replica of live site, you can uninstall all extensions one by one and check what is reason behind it. also is there any other errors you are seeing ? because `There has been an error processing your request"` is common error that will display for lot of reasons, if you post new question with error screenshot you may get help soon.